# How to know if a child theme is being used?

Tags: theme-development

I have inherited the job of editing my agency's webpage. I didn't create the site, and I am not sure whether the IMW custom theme that is active is a child type theme for 2011, or whether all customizations up to this point have been made to the original theme.  Do need to create a child theme for this site, how to do that considering all the customizations that have already been applied.

What do I need to provide to support for answers

I read some of the answer posts but still am unsure. So If I do not see "Child" in the CSS, then it is not a child theme? I was thinking that maybe the IMW Custom theme was a child theme itself based on the 2011 theme, just without the word child being used to designate it as such. IF IT IS NOT A CHILD THEME, then all of the customizations up to this point have been done to the theme itself. How would I go about creating a child theme from this point? I am so confused.

Comment: You can disable the child theme and see what happens, typically a child theme `style.css` has the following tag at the top `Template: parent theme name here`

Comment: No. That isn't really what the answers say. Read carefully. For example, you aren't looking for "Child" in the stylesheet; you are looking for "Template:"

Answer (score 11):

- Read the stylesheet. A child stylesheet ***must have*** `Template:
  somethemename` to function as a child theme.
- Look in Appearance -> Themes. A child theme should have a notice
  about requiring a parent theme.
- Use code similar to this (note: debugging only):

  ```
  add_action(
    'wp_head',
    function () {
      if (get_template_directory() === get_stylesheet_directory()) {
        echo 'not a child';
      } else {
        echo 'child';
      }
    }
  );
  ```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Nice collection. I like your 3rd option, but I think I would use `wp_footer` instead of `wp_head` or wrap the result inside a HTML comment `<!-- -->` (+1)

Comment: That is why I said "debugging only". The code just throws content onto the page with zero concern for layout or markup. It is purely "proof of concept".

Comment: I know ;-) This was actually just a comment for the other readers that are going to test this on their live sites regardless ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since WP 3.0 there is a function [is_child_theme()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_child_theme/) that returns a bool value.

Comment: And returns a PHP warning on 7+ for referencing constants without quotes - better get_template_directory() === get_stylesheet_directory()

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find any CSS in the Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS section, but the current theme has clearly been modified from another theme, follow the Wordpress guide on [Creating a Child Theme from a Modified Existing Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Creating_a_Child_Theme_from_a_Modified_Existing_Theme).

The Wordpress explanation clearly walks through how to use a DIFF tool to identify where changes have been made. Keep in mind that this does assume you can find the original, unmodified theme. There's [a link to a "worst case scenario" tutorial](http://techblog.kjodle.net/2014/04/12/wordpress-child-themes-the-whys-and-hows/#What_if_I8217ve_already_made_changes_to_my_original_theme), which sounds like what you might be facing.